# Can I use a physical copy of a psn plus free game to play it?

Tags: ps4, psn, cities-skylines

So I got cities skylines for free with psn plus trial, I do not plan to renew my psn plus, but if I went and bought cities skylines for ps4 from a store such as eb games. Will I be able to play it using the physical copy?

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to play the game but not without the disk. The only way you can play it without the disk (without PS plus) is if you buy the digital version.